# convert matlab code to c code

Tags: matlab

is there s a way to convert simulink blocks or a matlab ".m" code to C code automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **convert** Simulink models or MATLAB m-code to C you need [**Real-Time Workshop**](http://www.mathworks.com/products/rtw/).
It supports only subset of MATLAB language and oriented for embedded systems.

Look also at other MatWorks products for code generation and application deployment:
http://www.mathworks.com/products

With MATLAB Compiler you will not get a C code, but a binary code, executable or library (dll), which will run on machines without MATLAB installed, but with MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) library. It quite large in size, and platform specific and I believe it has to match the MATLAB version of compiled code.

For the new coming release 2011a The MathWorks developed new code generation products: *MATLAB Coder*, *Simulink Coder* and *Embedded Coder*.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any direct translation tool, but there are a few alternatives:

1. [Matlab Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) will let you create a shared library (callable from C code) from your .m code.
2. [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is an open source interpreter that has many of the same functions as Matlab. It is open source, and written in C. You might feasibly build a C library based on on this, although it would be a lot more heavy-weight than option (1).

Comment: But I think you need a license that supports Matlab compiler.

Comment: Correct -- you would need to pay for the Matlab Compiler. A potential option 3: Octave can also be used as a shared library (look in the documentation for "#include <octave/oct.h>" . This might be a happy medium: translate the basic .m code to C++ manually, using the high-level matlab-style functions provided by the Octave API.